# Text and label centered in CSS circle

Tags: css, text-alignment

I'm trying to create something approximately like the following in CSS:

[image]

where the `+2` is centered horizontally and vertically in the circle and the `DEX` is centered horizontally below the `+2`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What RPG tool are you building?

Comment: I'm writing an open-source web app to manage Dungeon World character sheets.

Comment: Thanks. Dungeon World looks like a return to the fun versions of D&D.

Comment: Dungeon World is big on storytelling and light on mechanics. I just started playing, but am enjoying it quite a bit.

Comment: I need to go back to playing, and this looks like something to try. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this.

```css
.circle {
  /* circle styles */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  /* become a flex container */
  /* its children will be flex items */
  display: flex;
  /* place items in column */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* center flex items horizontally */
  align-items: center;
  /* center all content vertically */
  justify-content: center;
}

/* simulate one more item to "balance" dex text */
.circle:before {
  content: "\A0";
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="number">+2</div>
  <div class="text">dex</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working well. I am using flexbox extensively in the rest of my webapp.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is using `line-height` to control vertical alignment of text, however that becomes unreliable when used along a global styling which adjusts the default line heights.

So, I suggest using the following solution which is much cleaner and easier to manage:

```css
.circle{
  width: 60px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding-top: 14px;
}
.circle span{
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  +12
  <span>dex</span>
</div>
```

**HTML**:
Use a `.circle` element as the actual circle and includes the number and a `<span>` element which holds the label.

**CSS**:
Use the `line-height` to control the spacing between the label and the number and I'm using the `padding-top` to push the number and center it vertically.

Comment: invalid code in snippet `margin-top: `